# How can I enter recovery mode (for Mac OS, on an iMac) remotely?

Tags: macos, keyboard, imac, startup, recovery

Our team administrates several Macs. To save costs (flights, etc.) in events where we have to remotely restore a system at our client location, we are trying to understand how to enter recovery mode without being physically present at the keyboard to enter recovery mode by pressing Cmd + R.

Can I pass a flag to `sudo reboot` or something similar, to initiate a reboot into recovery mode?

(All of the internet searches I've done have turned up "Press this series of keys on the keyboard" to enter various flavors of recovery.)

Comment: Even if you could issue a command to restart to the Recovery HD, what are you going to do next, you'll not have any connectivity to proceed further.

Comment: Networking isn't up by default? I'll have a hardwired connection...

Comment: Networking is up but how do you intend to retake control?

Comment: Honestly I had hoped to use vnc or ssh. Are those services not available?

Comment: Coming from the world of pxe-boot installs and unattend.xml for Windows installations, I was hoping for something similar.

Comment: When booting to the Recovery HD it is coming from a read-only image to a GUI interface in which one chooses what to do next from the dialog box presented or from the menu. I do not believe there is anything running that one can initiate connectivity remotely, but I've not tried.

Comment: Are you not using a MDM (mobile device management) solution for the Macs, such as JAMF Pro? An MDM can provide anything you would need for this.

Comment: @SamAndrew81 No MDM services.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can set NVRAM options from command line to boot into recovery:

```
sudo nvram "recovery-boot-mode=unused"
sudo reboot
```

This will put your system into recovery mode.

NVRAM (nonvolatile random-access memory) is a small amount of memory that holds certain settings and can be accessed at boot by the Mac's firmware.

Comment: Great info, thanks - where would I have found this if I were searching the docs on my own? (Teach a man to fish ....)

Comment: (And I'll test this once I'm in front of a mac that I can reset "remotely" (from the next desk over) and locally observe the results.)

Comment: @user3.1415927, Those commands will take you to a [screen like this one](https://imgur.com/a/uDVArpP) which then on a standard install of macOS you'll not have any remote control over. Also, trying to `ssh` returned `ssh: connect to host nnn.nnn.n.n port 22: Connection refused`. You'll need to use third-party software as suggested in the comment by SamAndrew81.